# Cannot check specific file in or out

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Using TFS 2017 with VS 2008, I checked a file out but can't remember what I did with it. I possibly should have deleted, but I replaced or overwrote it with a new one.

On my side, the file shows as "new". But when checking it in, a conflict arises because:

> Another file with the same name exists on the server.

Choosing *Keep local version* or *Keep server version* changes nothing, because

> There are already pending changes.

Comparing the files is not an option, as they are binary Crystal Reports files. I tried deleting the file, getting latest, getting a specific version; nothing works.

I can delete the conflicting file on my workspace because I have a local backup. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to delete the file from TFS, and recheck in. Possible of wrong map folder too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Will try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error  prompted, there was a file with the same name as the specific file you want to check in.

If you don't need the file and source control history in TFS any more. You could [tf destroy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control) the file, unlike delete, this will permanently delete, version-controlled files from TFS. And the destroy action cannot be reversed. Then just check in a totally new file.

If you want to keep the original file and history, instead of delete and create a new file with same name, you have to modify the file got from  TFS server. Delete local  workspace and create a new one, get latest version of the file, modify the file with local changes in your backup "new" version, finally check in the file again.